# if Outlook conditional statement

Tags: html, outlook

Is there a conditional statement for all Outlook versions?

I found this for version 9:

```
<!–[if gte mso 9]>
<![endif]–>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Linux at the moment and can't test, but perhaps something like `[if mso]`?